# How can I Use generated id in other fields in document in a single insert

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to create a file with the document id on it's name like ("[document_id].png"). But the database document must contain the file path so basically what I am doing:

```
insertFileDatabase() //saves database document without file path and return inserted id
createFile() //create file with the inserted id and return file path
updateFileDatabase() //updates database document file inserting the file path
```

Is there a way I can do this without need to update the document? To avoid making two database requests.

Comment: If you can generate the file path from the _id, you can generate the _id first, insert into the database using that id, and then create the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [MongoDB Go driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/), you could just create the ID first, then use that to insert. For example:

```go
  myId := primitive.NewObjectID()

  myPath, _ := createFile(myId) // create a file with the generated id and return file path 

  insertFileDatabase(myId, myPath) // insert into database a document with file path and id.
```

Please note that this `_id` will be in the form of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid). ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and ordered. ObjectId values are 12 bytes in length.

For more information see [primitive.NewObjectID](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#NewObjectID)